# comparing input with existing data from room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to login for the user using email and password from roomDatabase but it seems that it is not comparing the data in the room with the input, any idea how to compare them?

this is the line where I'm using

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE email Like :email AND password Like :password")
fun loginUser(email: String?, password: String?):  User?
```

and this is when I call it in the repository

```
suspend fun loginUser(email: String?, password: String?)=groovyDataBase.userDao().loginUser(email, password)
```

this is in the user view model

```
fun loginUser(email:String, password:String){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        groovyRepo.loginUser(email, password)
    }
}
```

and this is onClick button login
onClick = {

```
                            if (email.isNotEmpty()&& password.isNotEmpty()){
                                     mUserViewModel.loginUser(email,password)
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context,
                                    "Successfully Login",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()
                                //navigate back to Home
                                navController.navigate("HomeScreen")
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    context,
                                    "Please Enter valid email & password",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show()
                            }

                        },
```

Comment: It may be important to show how the password is inserted to database, because password should be encoded, not kept in plain string, but in your code, it seems, you are looking for the plain string password. If you are using some encoding during the insert, you should apply the same encoding before querying

Comment: In your code you are not checking the retrieved value from database, as your code implemented after  'mUserViewModel.loginUser' you should check if retrieved user in valid or 'null', then you can login the user